# Missing Parameters for JS Function, Still Works?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, scope, arguments

I've been struggling with the idea of when to receive/pass parameters to JavaScript functions and reading this article on [`onchange` event handlers at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange#Example) helped me crystallize my question. Here's the code from the article:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something here, then click outside of the field." size="50">
<p id="log"></p>
```

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let log = document.getElementById('log');

input.onchange = handleChange; //<<< Question on this <<<<<<

function handleChange(e) {
  log.textContent = `The field's value is
      ${e.target.value.length} character(s) long.`;
}
```

I see that `input` has an `onchange` Event handler that provides data to the `handleChange()` function. It even states that in the docs:

> The function receives an Event object as its sole argument.

Yet, I'm struggling to understand how `handleChange()` is receiving the Event object when it doesn't have parentheses accepting any argument?

`input.onchange = handleChange; // Where's the parentheses?`

Is the Event object global and that's how `handleChange()` is manipulating it? If that were the case, couldn't you omit the `e` argument when defining the function?

Comment: I realized now what I've been confused by: the difference between a function reference and a listener. 

For example Event Handlers take a function reference which is either a function name or function expression. Examples of Event Handlers include onclick and onchange.

Whereas, Event Listeners take a listener which is an object or function that implements the Event. Event listeners are applied to event types such as scroll, click, keydown and mouseenter.

Answer (score 4):

On the line in question, you're assigning a method as the handler (literally, setting a property of the input object to be a method reference). You are not calling that method. The browser is then responsible for creating an `Event` object and passing it to `handleChange` *each time it detects that an appropriate `onChange` event has taken place*.

It's the difference between telling your friend the phone number of the pizza place and your friend ordering a different pizza at five separate times.

Comment: Right, that makes sense "you are not calling that method". I also appreciate the analogy as well. I think I need to research "method reference" as you lost me there.

Comment: javascript Is one of those enlightened languages in which you can specify, refer to, and pass around functions just as easily as you can do all that with primitive values like strings and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The `onchange` atttribute normally takes a function as a value (the function that is called when something changes in this case). So the 'normal' form is:

```
input.onchange = function (e) { .... };
```

The notation you have in your code comes down to exactly the same, except that because you made handleChange a separate function it can be reused.

Comment: I get that. How does handleChange receive the Event argument if it doesn't have parentheses?

Comment: it has the parentheses on the function you attach to it, you are assigning `handleChange` without parentheses because if you would add the parentheses it would be executing the function at that point.

Comment: Gotcha! That ties into what Jasdeep wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.onchange = handleChange;
```

Above statement states that we are defining a function when a change event happens on input. If we add paranthesis, then it will call the function which we don't want.

It is way of assigning handlers to event. The handlers get executed when actual event happens.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This definitely clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

By `input.onchange = handleChange;` you are only telling the program that whenever the input is changed then you should call `handleChange` function. You don't need to specify the arguments.

All the events are handled internally. Whenever the event is triggered the `EventObject` is automatically passed to the function.

Consider the below example which used setInterval and a function with one argument

```js
//The below function is just like handleChange()
function test(num){
  console.log(num);
}

const object = {}; //Its just like "input" element object
object.func = test; //its just like setting input.onchange = handleChange

//This is an example of the function which calculates or creates an event object and then pass it to the defined function
function callFuncOfObject(){
  let valueCalculated = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  test(valueCalculated);
}

setInterval(callFuncOfObject, 1000)
```

Comment: That first part makes sense. Then you wrote, "All the events are handled internally". Does this mean the Event is a global object? I just compared the MDN docs of Window vs Event and both are interfaces. I recall reading that Window is a global object, so based on both concepts, I've inferred that both are global objects which is why `handleChange()` can access it.

Comment: @DaniAmsalem Whenever an event occurs, System creates a new event object based on that event. `EventObject` is not single or static object which is passed to each event instead its created on different events.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that! Since you didn't contradict me on the global aspect of it, I'm guessing that I was correct with regards to each Event being a global object.